# Wondering on how to fix trying to delete command once executed on discord sever

Tags: bots, discord.js

I was trying to make a bot command where if someone says the _apply they will get the message of the bot in the channel and after 50 seconds the bot will delete what the bot replied with the person who executed the command. This is the code that I have and tried to work with. I am using a separate file and not pasting the code in the index.js or bot.js file. If someone can help me out or guide me on what to do, it will help me a lot!

```
Error code that I am getting: (node:5900) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied options is not an object.
    at Message.delete (C:\Users\ljere\Desktop\BCSSRP\BCSSRP\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Message.js:501:44)     
    at ApplyCommand.run (C:\Users\ljere\Desktop\BCSSRP\BCSSRP\src\commands\apply\ApplyCommand.js:10:21)
    at MessageEvent.run (C:\Users\ljere\Desktop\BCSSRP\BCSSRP\src\events\message\message.js:17:17)
```

```js
const BaseCommand = require('../../utils/structures/BaseCommand');

module.exports = class ApplyCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('apply', 'apply', []);
  }

  run(client, message, args) {
    message.reply("You must choose which department you want to apply for.").then(d_message => { d_message.delete(50000); });
    message.delete(50000)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using discord.js@v12, where the `Message.delete()` method expects an object as a parameter, instead of the number for the time to wait. Check out the docs here: [v11](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=delete), [stable](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete)

```js
run(client, message, args) {
  message.reply('You must choose which department you want to apply for.').then(m => m.delete({ timeout: 50000 }))
  message.delete({ timeout: 50000 })
}
```